# White outline on the black background of the model, black outline outside the model

Tags: materials

I saw an interesting visual effect on the Cartoon Meowscles skin in Fortnite. This skin is made in the style of old cartoons of the 30s, Meowscles on the skin has a two-color outline, the white color of the outline appears on a black background, and the black outline distinguishes the character from the background (game landscape graphics).

I would like to repeat this effect. I was offered to use Fresnel node, I tried it, but I succeeded partially. Maybe I should use the character model as a mask for the white layer?

Can someone explain how to repeat the effect or provide a link to a tutorial, because I couldn't find a video explaining a similar effect.

Here's a link to a video demonstrating the skin in motion: [youtube.com/watch?v=qhhKf73hBFg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhhKf73hBFg)

[image: Toon Meowscles from Fortnite]
[image: Art Toon Meowscles]
[image]